# plot multiple density plots in one graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to plot multiple density plots in one graph, using ggplot2:

My `df` looks like this:

```
structure(list(item_count = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 8L), created_at = structure(c(18319, 18321, 18319, 
18321, 18319, 18321, 18319, 18321, 18319, 18321, 18319, 18321
), class = "Date"), frequency = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 586L, 419L, 
268L, 238L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(item_count = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10, 
    11L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

aka:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   item_count [7]
   item_count created_at frequency
        <int> <date>         <int>
 1          1 2020-02-27         2
 2          1 2020-02-29         2
 3          2 2020-02-27         3
 4          2 2020-02-29         6
 5          3 2020-02-27       586
 6          3 2020-02-29       419
 7          4 2020-02-27       268
 8          4 2020-02-29       238
 9          5 2020-02-27         5
10          5 2020-02-29         2
11          6 2020-02-27         1
12          8 2020-02-29         1
```

I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(item_count, frequency), colors=created_at) + geom_density()
```

getting this error:

```
Error: geom_density requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably not the best error message. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3514 on this issue. The point is that `geom_density` like `geom_histogram` is meant to visualize the distribution of one variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(item_count, frequency, col = created_at)) + 
  geom_density(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: I still get an error `Error in f(...) : Aesthetics can not vary with a ribbon`

Answer (score 0):

You already have the frequency of your items, so it's a matter of joining the lines:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=item_count,y=frequency,col=factor(created_at))) + geom_line()
```

[image]

You can reconstruct the later like this to get a density, but I think your frequency table is odd:

```
obs = data.frame(counts=rep(df$item_count,df$frequency),
created_at=rep(df$created_at,df$frequency))

ggplot(obs,aes(x=counts,col=factor(created_at))) + geom_density(bw=0.33)
```

Might need to find a suitable `bw`

[image]

observed_data

Comment: using `factor()` works. I would like to have density plot; if I use `geom_density()` I get `Error: geom_density requires the following missing aesthetics: y`

Comment: to clarify, to do a density plot, you need the actual observations, not summarized like what you have. I can edit my answer to show how you can recover the counts, but honestly i don't think it is right and you should check whether the raw data is correct

Comment: from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation, you need the observations of the random variable to make a density plot.